# How to trigger your automation script from VSTS and get the test execution result back in VSTS

Tags: azure-devops

I have a automation script which built in Java/selenium. I want to run my test cases from VSTS by triggering my script and also want to get the result back in VSTS. Can anybody give me the path how can I make that happen. Also where should I keep by project?

I was doing research on it. But doesn't make sense to me
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/test/continuous-test-selenium?view=azure-devops

Answer (score 0):

> run my test cases from VSTS by triggering my script and also want to
>   get the result back in VSTS

For this issue ,there is a [blog](http://www.atlefren.net/post/2018/07/vsts-setting-up-tests-and-coverage-to-run-on-build-for-javascript-projects/) that gives a path to do this , please refer to it to see if it helps .

In this path , you need to do stuff both to your project, and to your vsts build definition. The jest-junit package is needed in the project and then create a build with three tasks(“npm”,“Publish Test Results”, “Publish Code Coverage Results” ).